# What is meant by the arithmetic simplification of an expression?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, terminology

I know what we mean by the algebraic simplification of an expression but don't know exactly what is meant by the arithmetic simplification of one. Will you kindly help me to figure out the difference between these two mathematical processes?
Illustrative examples are warmly welcome.

My best guess would be $5+3=8$ is an arithmetic simplification while $5x^2+3x^2=8x^2$ is an algebraic simplification. Is it the case or something else?

**PS:** I got across the term "arithmetically and algebraically simplifying expressions" at https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~kouba/CalcTwoDIRECTORY/partialfracdirectory/PartialFrac.html.

Comment: Yes. I suppose a general definition might involve the equivalent expression with smallest leaf count.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This term has no precise meaning and is not being used with any precise meaning in the context in which you have encountered it.  The entire phrase "arithmetically and algebraically simplifying expressions" is just referring to all the simplifications you might do with an expression, which could involve both algebra and arithmetic.  It is certainly not meaning to imply that there is any well-defined distinction in which some simplifications are "algebraic" and others are "arithmetic".